# Ubuntu 18.4 LTS With NVMe SSD On board Work slower than Normal SSD

Tags: boot, 18.04, ssd, performance, nvme

Build new ubuntu 18.4 desktop with NVMe SSD, detail configuration as below

- Samsung 970 EVO Plus 250 GB NVMe M.2 PCIe Internal Solid State Drive (MZ-V7S250BW)
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 8GB DDR4 3000 (PC4-24000) C16 PC Memory (CMK8GX4M1D3000C16)
- AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega 8 Graphics Desktop Processor 4 Cores up to 3.7GHz 6MB Cache AM4 Socket (YD2200C5FBBOX)
- GIGABYTE GA-A320M-S2H AMD A320 AM4 MAX-32GB DDR4 Micro ATX PCIE16

With Above configuration I had new desktop, which works slower than normal SSD. As on boot time, as well its work slower than normal SSD.

SSD NVMe M.2 claim 3000 MB / second transfer but its slower to transfer data as well.

I had already set

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Please guide me, how can I resolve slow issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200"
```

And then update the GRUB.

Comment: Guide me pre step(which file to edit), steps(where to put in file) and post step(any cross check to do), do I need restart system ?